# Series control flow with bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I have a number of promises and I want to execute them in order, but conditionally.

For example, I have the following promises:

`getItems()`

`getItemsSource()`

`getItemsAlternativeSource()`

What I want to do is try `getItems()` first.  If this resolves with an empty value OR if it throws an error, I want to log that error (if that's the case), but then try `getItemsSource()`, same as above, if it resolves with no value or throws an error, I want to log the error if that's the case and try `getItemsAlternativeSource()`.

I know I can do this conditionally, in each `then()` or `catch()`, but that seems a bit redundant.  Is there a better way to handle this kind of control flow?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an empty value as the return value of the `catch` handler:

```
getItems().catch(function(err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return null; // <==
}).then(function(items) {
    if (items) return items;
    else return getItemsSource().catch(function(err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return null; // <==
    }).then(function(sourceitems) {
        if (items) return items;
        else return getItemsAlternativeSource().catch(function(err) {
            console.warn(err);
            throw new Error("items couldn't be fetched normally, from source, or from alternative source");
        });
    });
});
```

---

If you absolutely want to avoid duplication, you can use this highly abstract approach:

```
var tryAll = [getItems, getItemsSource, getItemsAlternativeSource].reduceRight(function(nextAlternative, fetch) {
    return function() {
        return fetch().then(function(items) {
            if (items) return items;
            else return nextAlternative(); // now we can even call it in two locations
        }, function(err) {
            console.warn(err);
            return nextAlternative(); // without having to resort to catch-then
        });
    };
}, function last() {
    throw new Error("items couldn't be fetched normally, from source, or from alternative source");
});
tryAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a function that takes an array of functions that will call each function in the array until one returns with some data.

```
function getFirstData(array) {
    var index = 0;
    function next() {
        if (index < array.length) {
            return array[index++]().then(function(data) {
                // if we got an answer, return it as the resolve value
                if (data) return data;
                // otherwise, reject so we go to the next one
                return Promise.reject(null);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                if (err) console.err(err);
                return next();
            });
        } else {
            // got to the end of the array without a value
            throw new Error("No data found");
        }
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(next);
}

var fns = [getItem, getItemsSource, getItemsAlternativeSource];

getFirstData(fns).then(function(data) {
    // got data here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // no data found here
});
```

If you want the functions to have arguments, then you can `.bind()` the arguments to the functions before putting them in the array.

---

And, here's a different implementation using `.reduce()` to traverse the array:

```
function getFirstData(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(p, fn) {
        return p.then(function(priorData) {
            // if we already got some data, then just return it
            // don't execute any more functions
            if (priorData) return priorData;
            return fn().catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return null;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function(data) {
        if (!data) {
            throw new Error("No data found");
        }        
    });
}
```